# IPTables Script to block Concurrent Connections

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, iptables

We are using Suse Linux Enterprise Server 12. We need to block concurrent IP Addresses which is hitting our web server for more thatn 50 times per second and block that ip address for 10 minutes. Also it should distinguish attacker and genuine traffic and block attacker's IP forever.  We have currently blocked using iptables , below is the rule.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set   
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
```

It will just block the IPAddress which  exceeds 50 connections but wont blacklist the IPAddress.  Please let us know if we have a script that will match all the scenarios which is metioned above.  Please Help.

Comment: The rules you have written will block new connections from the same IP address if requests (SYN) exceed 50 in 1 second.  If it does it will block the IP address for 1 second.  You can find lots of examples of how to accomplish the task.  Be careful that any implementation of automated IP Blacklisting like this is susceptible to denial of service by spoofing the source IP.  Inadvertent blocking can also happen if someones browser gets into a loop.   fail2ban is a great tool aimed at solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and it works really nice.  If the behavior is detected, the IP is put into hold-down for 10 minutes and logged. You can verify it's operation by watching these files.  /proc/net/xt_recent/NICE, /proc/net/xt_recent/NAUGHTY.  You need to build a script to parse the log for bad IP's and commit them to a file that is loaded into iptables on startup if you want to blacklist permanently.  That concept is already clear so no need for me to include it.

```
#flush and clear
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F 
iptables -X

#this is where naughty kids go
iptables -N GETCAUGHT

#you got added to the naughty list 
iptables -A GETCAUGHT -m recent --name NAUGHTY --set                   #everyone here is bad
iptables -A GETCAUGHT -j LOG --log-prefix "iwasbad: " --log-level 4    #and it goes on your permanent record

#if you are on the NAUGHTY list you get a lump of coal                                
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --name NAUGHTY --rcheck --seconds 600 -j DROP       #check everyone at the door

#though everyone starts out on the NICE list
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --name NICE --set     #you seem nice

#but if you GETCAUGHT doing this you are naughty 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --name NICE --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 --update -j GETCAUGHT    #that wasn't nice
```

Comment: The command "iptables -F" will flush your INPUT chain.  That is where UFW and Fail2Ban store their rules - so that will destroy your firewall.  Even if you're not using UFW and Fail2Ban, most equivalent service also use iptables in the same way.  You could add your rules in without calling iptables -F and iptables -X.  I don't have enough knowledge to comment on "iptables -F -t nat" but would advise more research and caution.

Comment: I though the comment was clear on that matter.  In fact this will flush everything in ALL chains and is designed that way such that a user can tweak settings and rerun until they are satisfied with the prototype. Use of the commands in this script assumes basic netfilter knowledge and user space programs, iptables and ufw alike.  Never simply copy and paste without understanding.  The work herein is designed to be an example to answer using a concept rather than being a-la-carte.  Please take what you need and integrate it into your battery of rules.  Thanks for your critique.